# Uploaded images not in image folder

Tags: php, mysql

I just made a file upload code and I was wondering why the file upload wasn't working? I checked the permission of my image folder in localhost and that seems to be ok. I don't know where the problem exactly is. Any ideas?

```
<?php 

require "config.php";
require "functions.php";
require "database.php";

if(isset($_FILES['fupload'])){
    $filename = addslashes($_FILES['fupload']['name']);
    $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
    $target = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;
    $description = addslashes($_POST['description']);
    $src = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;
    $tn_src = $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename;

    if (strlen($_POST['description'])<4)
        $error['description'] = '<p class="alert">Please enter a description for your photo</p>';
    if($filename == '' || !preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)|(jpeg)$/', $filename)) 
        $error['no_file'] = '<p class="alert">Please select an image, dummy! </p>';
    if (!isset($error)){
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

        $q = "INSERT into photo(description, src, tn_src)VALUES('$description', '$src','$tn_src')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($q) or die (mysqli_error($myqli));

        if ($result) {
            echo "Succes! Your file has been uploaded";
        }
        createThumbnail($filename);
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My photos</h1>

    <ul><?php getPhotos(); ?></ul>
    <h2>Upload a photo</h2>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
        <input type="file" name="fupload" /><br/>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload photo" name="submit" />
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($error["description"])) {
        echo $error["description"];
    }

    if (isset($error["no_file"])) {
        echo $error["no_file"];
    }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you on windows? Is localhost on C://?

Comment: Hi, no I use OSX. Btw the uploaded image is stored in the database. My only problem is that the image not show in my image folder.

Comment: Does the user that's running Apache/Nginx have write permission to that folder?

Comment: What's the value of `$path_to_thumbs_directory`?

Comment: I can think two possibilities: (a) you have an error in your image folder path or (b) php has no access in that folder.
Can you tell us what is the value of $path_to_thumbs_directory?

Comment: $path_to_image_directory = 'images/';
$path_to_thumbs_directory = 'images/tn/';

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you appended directory separator in $path_to_thumbs_directory.
And you don't need to use addslashes to $filename.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174